# Android efficiency importing static methods or importing the class

Tags: java, android, performance, static, static-methods

I've seen in some projects people importing directly a static method into an Activity or a class instead of the whole class.

My question is, knowing that a static method can be called several times (*for being more accurate, 5 or more times*) in the same class, is it more efficient to import the static method or it is better to call it through its class?

Comment: Better to call through a class. static stuff makes a mess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question (according to me) does seems to address the same point.
The question is if:
is calling  `ClassName.staticMethod()` directly

or this

```
import static ClassName.staticMethod;
//rest of the stuff
staticMethod();
```

In both cases, the methods are loaded as a singleton whenever the class is called first.If you import the static method,then thats the first time or else when you use the class's method.

So it wont make a difference because the JVM/DVM (not sure about ART) already has the data required.

IF however your question is regarding what modifiers to use,then [this](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#PreferStatic) advocates static.

But as mentioned,involving static methods directly is just messy.
So now its more of a personal choice.
Read as:Do not import static methods directly unless you have a very specific reason to do so.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference in performance between static imports and import the class.

However, import the class and use the class name to call static methods is considered a better practice, because the code is more easy to read. With static imports it could be a bit confusing which methods are non-static methods of the class and which methods are static methods of other classes.